# Is it possible to have a listmenu in tornadofx workspace

Tags: tornadofx

I have tried to add list menu in tornadofx workspace but it appears in the right side in the header .
How to add a fixed list menu at left {}

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically target the `left` part of the `BorderPane` inside of a `Workspace` like this:

```
workspace.root.left {
    listview(someValues)
}
```

A good place to do this would be in `onDock`, or inside of your `Workspace` subclass.

There is also a `wrapper {}` builder you can use to add UI elements around the actual workspace area if you need to customize the workspace layout further.